# Download TAR through PHP

Tags: php, download, tar

I need to download all files in a directory so I started by creating a (non-gziped) tar of all those files. This tar is valid and can be accessed correctly on the server but unfortunately, I can't seem to download it correctly through PHP. I get an error saying 'Unknown or corrupt image file!' when I try to open the downloaded tar file.

Here's my php file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<?php
  $filename = '/path/to/my.tar';

  header( 'Content-type: archive/tar' );
  header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename( $filename ) . '"'  );
  header( 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary' );
  header( 'Content-Length: ' . filesize( $filename ) );
  readfile( $filename );
?>
```

Also, I've tried a few different header variations for eg:

```
header( 'Content-type: application/x-tar' );
header( 'Content-type: application/force-download' );
```

I have the same problem regardless. Out of ideas....

Comment: dont use a tar file for windows users, it confuses them

Comment: if i manually transfer the tar file from the server to the windows machine, it works fine, so there's nothing wrong with the tar file. Also, it's not an end user application so this is not an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove doctype declaration, the very first line of this PHP file must be `<?php` without any spaces or any other symbols before this, at the end remove `?>` as it is not needed

it was not working because you were downloading file which actually started with lines from you code and only after it binary code of tar archive, this is why you were not able to open this file, as it is not really tar file after addition of text lines at the beginning of it